# How to place progress bar in specific field of status bar in wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, statusbar

The following code places progress bar in the 1st field of status bar:

```
self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
self.statusbar.SetFieldsCount(3)
self.statusbar.SetStatusWidths([320, -1, -2])

self.progress_bar = wx.Gauge(self.statusbar, -1, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL|wx.GA_SMOOTH)
```

How to place progress bar in field no. 2 of status bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put a progress bar (guage) in the statusbar area and lock the gui size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919564/how-to-put-a-progress-bar-guage-in-the-statusbar-area-and-lock-the-gui-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice custom extension of the status bar called the EnhancedStatusBar that you can find here: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/EnhancedStatusBar.html

It allows you add pretty much any widget to the status bar. Here's an example of adding a progress bar to the second field of the status bar using this widget:

```
import EnhancedStatusBar
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Enhanced Statusbar Demo")
        panel = MyPanel(self)


        self.statusbar = EnhancedStatusBar.EnhancedStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.SetSize((-1, 23))
        self.statusbar.SetFieldsCount(2)
        self.SetStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.progress = wx.Gauge(self.statusbar, range=20)
        self.statusbar.AddWidget(self.progress, pos=1)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.updateGauge)
        self.timer.Start(100)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateGauge(self, event):
        """"""
        self.progress.Pulse()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Tested with Python 2.6 / wxPython 2.8 and Python 2.7 / wxPython 2.9 on Windows 7. It doesn't appear to work with wxPython 3, however.